# Last inserted ID of a table for another table in the same query?

Tags: php

I have a register, were people can register with their username, their email and a password. If this gets successfully transmitted to the database, this data will be inserted into a table called `users`. Now, I need the last ID from the just registered user for a second table that is called `users_tokens`, where I obviously want to save a token for every specific user. I've tried to solve this by using $mysql->insert_id; but that returns 0 in the table and I am also curious if this is a safe method since through my websites data gets inserted all the time.

My PHP Script:

```
    $key = getToken(32);
    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64));

    $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, verification_key, register_date) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_POST["name"], $_POST["email"], md5($_POST["password"]), $key, $posted_on);

    $lastid = $mysql->insert_id;
    $u_token = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO users_tokens (uid, token) VALUES(?,?)");
    $u_token->bind_param("ss", $lastid, $token);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to execute your statement before retrieving `insert_id`, something like this

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, verification_key, register_date) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_POST["name"], $_POST["email"], md5($_POST["password"]), $key, $posted_on);
$stmt->execute(); //You should check for correct execution
$lastid = $mysql->insert_id;
```

Comment: Thanks man, that did it. Bless you. Would you say it's safe to do it this way?